# Does Facebook mark messages as unseen automatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm a little bit curious. Does Facebook mark messages as unseen automatically?
After some passing days I see that my message to a friend becomes unseen. Is it done automatically or what ?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Facebook message wont be deleted until you have removed manually otherwise it would be fully shown

Answer (score 1):

Go to view full conversation and then you will be able to see seen of the last message you sent to someone. In chat window mode, it goes away to minimise clutter in chat window.